# send array in module.exports in promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, seneca

I am working on merge swagger files. I want to pass array like

```
[ 
  { method: '1', path: '/signIn', handler: funation() {return "abcd"},
  { method: '2', path: '/signOut', handler: funation() {return "123"},
]
```

I get result as per my need but it was not pass into module.exports, i have check it into another file console after require this file,
my code is like

```
jsonResolve(root, options).then(function (results) {
  const result = results.resolved.paths;
  // console.log(result);
  for (key in result) {
    // console.log('keys', key);
    const apiRoute = key;
    const apiDescription = result[key];
    let controller = apiDescription['x-swagger-router-controller'];
    for (method in apiDescription) {
      // console.log("methods", method);
      let newRoute = {};
      if (method !== 'x-swagger-router-controller') {
        let operationId1 = apiDescription[method].operationId;

        newRoute = {
          method: method,
          path: apiRoute,
          handler: controllers[controller][operationId1](),
        };
        exoprtData.push(newRoute);
      }
    }
  }
  return exoprtData;
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  module.exports = result;
})
```

I had check it result into last then. but not pass into module.exports

my require file code is like,

```
var ApiRoutes = require("./routes/api");
console.log("ApiRoutes", ApiRoutes);
```

And here i get result into console like

```
ApiRoutes {}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: "Module should export function not data"

Comment: You cannot asynchronously assign to `module.exports`. Try exporting the promise for the routes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js expects any module to be loaded synchronously - ie. you **must** assign to `module.exports` in the current execution loop, otherwise the module's exported content will be a default empty object.

You are assigning to `module.exports` after you resolve a promise. **This will not work** - by the time the promise is resolved, Node.js already finished loading your module and cached the exported value (empty object) as the module's contents. You cannot change it by assigning to `module.exports` now.

To solve this problem, you must either:

- export a function which returns the array through promise
- Somehow make it work synchronously (depends on what `jsonResolve()` does)
- Assign the actual promise to `module.exports`

Comment: You can synchronously assign the promise to `module.exports` (instead of the promise's result)